# How can I prevent the android virtual keyboard from obscuring content? Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am solving the following problem. I have a 'navbar' like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">PPŘ</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">ŠKOLENÍ<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">ODKAZY</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">LEGISLATIVA</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">INFO PORTÁL</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#login" data-toggle="collapse" role="button"
                data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#loginDropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Přihlásit se</a>
            <!-- Přihlašovací formulář -->
            <div class="dropdown-menu" id="loginDropdown" style="max-height:200px; overflow-y:auto; position: relative">
            <form class="px-4 py-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleDropdownFormEmail1">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormEmail1" placeholder="email@example.com">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleDropdownFormPassword1">Heslo</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormPassword1" placeholder="Heslo">
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="dropdownCheck">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="dropdownCheck">Pamatuj si mně</label>
                </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            </form>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Jsi zde po prvé? Registruj se!</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Hledej..." aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Vyhledat</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

It works flawlessly on a desktop computer. But the problem is on the mobile device.
After clicking on the 'Login' option in the navbar, the login form will open. The problem occurs when you click on the input field of this form and a virtual keyboard opens, which covers almost the entire login form. I would like the android virtual keyboard to push this login form above each other.

I tried to solve the problem. Define the relative position of the  element with the form. Like this:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="loginDropdown" style="max-height:200px; overflow-y:auto; position: relative">
```

However, the problem cannot be solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: You'll have to add a height based media query to change and change the CSS accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. I only know the basic things about css. How is such a media height query performed? Can you please give an example? Thank you. @NigelDcruz

Comment: Sure, I've written an answer for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the device keyboard opens up the actual viewport size decreases. This is causing the problem that you're facing.

**Solution:**
You need to add a height based CSS media query. You'll have to check the viewport size when the keyboard is open and add the required CSS in the media query.

**Eg:**
The below media query checks the height of the viewport and adds a black background to all the elements.

```
@media screen and (max-height: 200px){ //Change 200 to viewport height after keyboard opns
  *{
    background-color: #000;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I can't handle it. I'm so screwed. @NigeDcruz

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me. @NigeDcruz